# remove the last path and duplicate the new last

Tags: go, path, filepath

I need to split item for path for example

`/Users/i0564454/go/src/projectA/node`

I need at the end it will be like this

`/Users/i0564454/go/src/projectA/projectA`

everything is the same except `remove` the last item and duplicate the (new) last item

Does file path can help without too many iterations ?
https://gowalker.org/path/filepath

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your attempts please.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible with the standard library too. You may use / combine:

- [`path.Dir()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Dir) to get the folder (remove the last element)
- [`path.Base()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Base) to get the last element
- and [`path.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Join) to join path elements.

Without error checking (e.g. if the passed path has folders), the following function does what you want:

```
func convert(s string) string {
    dir := path.Dir(s)
    return path.Join(dir, path.Base(dir))
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(convert("/Users/i0564454/go/src/projectA/node"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0IgpxqEkDry)).

```
/Users/i0564454/go/src/projectA/projectA
```

Note that package `path` handles slash-separated paths. If you need / want to support OS-specific paths, use the identical functions of the [`path/filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) package.